# how to get year between two months along with month and dates in sql query oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to extract no of years, months between two months, for example my output looks like `1year 9months`. I don't know how to display output like this, below is the query which I am using now.

```
select round((MONTHS_BETWEEN(lease_end_date,lease_start_date)/12),1) Duration_In_Years
from lease_header
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846096/17015855) is probably what you are looking for. You can always format the given interval with TO_CHAR

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Read comments within code:

```
SQL> with test (date_1, date_2) as
  2    -- sample dates; to test the query, modify these values
  3    (select date '2021-10-20', date '2020-09-01' from dual),
  4  temp as
  5    -- split result of MONTHS_BETWEEN to number of years and number of months
  6    (select
  7       trunc(months_between(date_1, date_2) / 12) yrs,
  8       round((months_between(date_1, date_2) / 12 - trunc(months_between(date_1, date_2) / 12)) * 12, 1) mon
  9     from test
 10    )
 11  -- final result
 12  select yrs || ' year(s) ' || mon || ' month(s)' result
 13  from temp;

RESULT
----------------------
1 year(s) 1,6 month(s)

SQL>
```

Comment: select trunc(months_between(lease.lease_end_date,(lease.lease_start_date)) / 12) || ' Years ' ||
 trunc(months_between(lease.lease_end_date,(trunc(lease.lease_start_date,'YY'))) -
 (trunc(months_between(lease.lease_end_date,(trunc(lease.lease_start_date,'YY'))) / 12) * 12)) || ' Months' ||' '||
 ( trunc(lease.lease_end_date)- add_months((trunc(lease.lease_start_date,'YY')),
  trunc(months_between(lease.lease_end_date,(trunc(lease.lease_start_date,'YY')))))) || ' Days ' 
 from dual


this is my query but my output is showing as 0 years 11 months 30 Days but i want 1 year 0 months 0 days